# preg_grep to get index instead of value

Tags: search, indexing

I have an array like

```
$arr = array("arif", "arin", "asif", "armin", "arpan");
```

I want to search and get the indices of the elements which meet a regex.
In this case I wanna get the indices `0, 1, 3, 4` as they match my pattern

```
$regex = '|^ar|';
```

Comment: Use `preg_grep`, and then `array_keys($resulting_arr)` ([demo](https://ideone.com/5yS9ZX))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) for that:

```
<?php

$arr = array("arif", "arin", "asif", "armin", "arpan");
$regex = '|^ar|';

$res = array_keys(preg_grep($regex, $arr));
var_dump($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each item in the array, test if your regular expression matches using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) the item, if it does, add the index to another array of indexes. If it doesn't match, simply continue. You'll be left with an array of indices.

```
$words = array("arif", "arin", "asif", "armin", "arpan");
$pattern = '|^ar|';

$indices = array();
foreach ($words as $i => $word) {
    // if there is a match
    if (preg_match($pattern, $word)) {
        // append the current index to the indices array
        $indices[] = $i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match` function while iterating through the input array:

```
$arr = array("arif", "arin", "asif", "armin", "arpan");
$keys = [];
foreach ($arr as $k => $item) {
    if (preg_match('/^ar/', $item)) $keys[] = $k;
}

print_r($keys);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```